# System.NullPointerException: null argument for JSONGenerator.writeStringField() test

Tags: apex, unit-test

I'm doing tests and I get the following error " System.NullPointerException: null argument for JSONGenerator.writeStringField() " I don't know exactly what I'm forgetting to do(I cannot receive null values)

```
public static String getLossInfoReq(Case cc){
    JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
    gen.writeStartObject();
    
    gen.writeStringField('policyNumber', cc.Contract__r.Name);
    gen.writeStringField('lossId', cc.ClaimNumber__c);
    
    gen.writeEndObject();
            
    String genString = gen.getAsString();
    
    return genString;
}
```

```
@IsTest
private static void get_Loss_Info_ReqTest(){
    String response;
    Case newCase = new Case();  
            
    PSR_HomeLossDetailParser psr = new PSR_HomeLossDetailParser();
    response = PSR_HomeLossDetailParser.getLossInfoReq(newCase);
            
    System.assert(response != null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it is failing at this line `gen.writeStringField('policyNumber', cc.Contract__r.Name);` when method `writeStringField` receives `null` argument - it throws NPE.

In your test, you created `Case` object, which is really empty. Thus calling `cc.Contract__r` is throwing a null pointer exception, as `cc.Contract__r` was not set in test, it is `null`.

You can do two steps:

check if the second parameter for writing a field is not `null`

```
if(cc.Contract__r.Name != null){
    gen.writeStringField('policyNumber', cc.Contract__r.Name);
}
```

the same for second string field writing.

add parent `Contract` to the `Case` in the test. (if you are using custom Contract field and to test positive test cases)  e.g

```
Contract newContract = new Contract(Name = 'Contract test name');    
Case newCase = new Case(ClaimNumber__c = 123, Contract__r = newContract);
```

Comment: `cc.Contract__r.Name` isn't responsible for the NPE here. We (effectively) get an implicit SNO when accessing a parent object (when the SObject is constructed in memory or if any parent field is included in a queried instance). So `cc.Contract__r?.Name` isn't going to help here.

Comment: @DerekF agree with you. `writeStringField` is not accepting any `null` argument at all.

Answer (score 1):

In unit tests, you are responsible for setting up *all of the data you need*.
As the error suggests, you can't pass a null value to `writeStringField()`. As your test Case is completely empty, all fields will be null.

So at the very least, you'll need to populate the Claim Number and Contract fields (and give the Contract a name).

```
Case c = new Case(
    ClaimNumber__c = 1,
    // Relationship fields are proper SObject instances, so we can
    //   put our own SObject instance into it for testing
    Contract__r = new Contract(Name = 'testContract')
);
```

Be aware that if you're running this code from a trigger, you cannot use the Case instances from the trigger context variables (TCVs). TCV instances do not contain any data on related records (so `c.Contract__r.Name` would be null). You'd need to explicitly query for that data.

That aside, as a general rule you do not want to use JSONGenerator or JSONParser. They're extremely verbose, prone to semantic issues, and we have a better way (`JSON.serialize()` and `JSON.deserialize()`/`JSON.deserializeUntyped()`).

Re-writing your getLossInfoReq method using this:

```java
getLossInfoReq(Case cc){
    // Map<String, Object> is very helpful when we want to make our own JSON
    //   because it can hold basically anything as a value including:
    //   - A List<Object> for JSON arrays
    //   - Another Map<String, Object> for nested JSON Objects
    //   - All the usual (primitive type) suspects, Integer, Boolean, String, etc...
    return JSON.serialize(new Map<String, Object>{
        'policyNumber' => cc.Contract__r.Name,
        'lossId' => cc.ClaimNumber__c
    });
}
```

Less typing, and it can accept null values. Whether or not you *want* to allow null values here is something you'll need to decide for yourself.