# Type requires name=value pair construction: Case test apex

Tags: apex

I am running tests on this Code but it returns this error " Type requires name=value pair construction: Case " , I don't know exactly what is missing.
(I cannot return null values)

```
public static String getLossInfoReq(Case cc){
    JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
    
    gen.writeStartObject();

    gen.writeStringField('policyNumber', cc.Contract__r.Name);
    gen.writeStringField('lossId', cc.ClaimNumber__c);

    gen.writeEndObject();
    
    String genString = gen.getAsString();

    return genString;
}
```

```
     @IsTest
    private static void get_Loss_Info_ReqTest(){
        
    
      String response;
      String policyNumber = '123';
      String lossId = '1';
    Case newCase = new Case(policyNumber, lossId);  
            
    PSR_HomeLossDetailParser psr = new PSR_HomeLossDetailParser();
    response = PSR_HomeLossDetailParser.getLossInfoReq(newCase);
            
    
    }
```

Comment: You need to specify field names in the constructor: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_sobjects

Comment: It wasn't explicitly covered, but it was demonstrated in both mine and Oleksandr's answers on [your previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/377232/system-nullpointerexception-null-argument-for-jsongenerator-writestringfield). If you're familiar with programming but not familiar with Apex, then https://trailhead.salesforce.com is going to be a good introduction. If you're not familiar with Object-Oriented programming (OOP) languages, then working on some base OOP knowledge will help you with Apex.

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you exactly what you are doing wrong and how to fix it. The problematic line is:

```
Case newCase = new Case(policyNumber, lossId);
```

You need to use field paths or relationship names to populate values onto this record. It should look more like:

```
Case newCase = new Case(
    ClaimNumber__c = lossId, // field = value
    Contact__r = new Contact( // here you have to use a relationship name instead
        Name = policyId
    )
);
```